# Angular: moving charts into different bindings

Tags: angularjs, html, dom, data-binding

New developer here working on some thing that's a little out of my depth.

I'd like to have dynamically generated charts into rotate into different, predetermined locations on my page.

for example:

> chart 1 
>   chart 2 
>   chart 3
>   would rotate thru a list of 5 charts to display
>   chart 2
>   chart 3
>   chart 4

I feel like my best option here is to create objects (JSON maybe?) of these charts and to have them stored in an array, then have the array loop through the binding locations and 'plop' (for lack of better word) the object's details into the next spot in the rotation, which theoretically would allow the chart to render in the new location; with a timer driving the changes.

I would probably use pre-set frames to designate the slots being rotated into, though I'm less positive that is the right way to handle that.

I know this is possible with angular, and despite my best efforts I cannot for the life of me determine the best way to go about this.  I'm really very open as to the method this gets done, but am at a complete loss on how to set up the data-binding framework to accomplish this.

Comment: if this is intended to be displayed all in a row (carousel style), it might be easier to just display and hide the right elements, instead of moving all the data between divs.

Comment: I was hoping to work out the animation of them moving from one slot to the other, but that was something i will work out later.

do you suggest that i have each one ready to be displayed in each box and just rotate which is being shown and which hidden?

Comment: Animation is usually also done on the container the content is in. That's how all those sliding images and carousels work. So yes, I suggest leaving my them in the container they're in, and just moving the containers.